# How to call a HttpPost method from Controller in ASP.net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, controller, call

I am unable to redirect to a post method from one of my action method.My code is given below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DepositForm(CASH_DEPOSIT cash_deposit)
{
    /*This line is not needed*/ ViewBag.ACCOUNT_ID = new SelectList(accountManager.GetAll(), "ID", "ACCOUNT_NUMBER");
    return RedirectToAction("ConfirmationPage",cash_deposit);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmationPage(CASH_DEPOSIT cash_deposit)
{
    return View(cash_deposit);
}
```

The DepositForm Method redirects to ConfirmationPage using GetMethod.How can I Post CASH_DEPOSIT class from DepositForm to ConfirmationPage?

Comment: What do you want to d with the cash_deposit in the ConfirmationPage? Have you placed a breakpoint on ConfirmationPage too see if the cash_deposit is being passed to the ActionMethod? If it is, you can do whatever you want with it..

Comment: In the confirmation page I want to show the cash_deposit and verify the user with an authentication code.If the verification completed then I submit the cash_deposit to the db.

Comment: Is the cash_deposit being passed to the ConfirmationPage ActionMethod? If it is you don't need a POST, you just need to pass the values to the view to display them, when the user enters the verification code and hits submit you grab these values and post them to another action method, maybe called confirm, and save them to the database. You could then redirect to a final action called success to show the user that everything worked well.

Comment: .If I pass the values using Session then when client refreshs the ConfirmationPage before submission all the values are gone.The form is submitted without values.But if confirmationpage used post method he can't do this.

Comment: How about just redisplaying the values with hidden fields in the confirmation page. When they click submit on that page, it'll send the data to the `[HttpPost]ConfirmationPage`

Comment: Dear Bataineh,I didn't get it.can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Interesting question, but eventually was totally ignored...